# Установка bootstrap4 в проект asp.net core

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Начал изучение asp.net core, устанавливаю через nuget bootstrap, но вместо папок со стилями и скриптами, устанавливаются только  зависимости. Изначально создавал пустой проект.Что я не так делаю?

Comment: у пакета есть описание, и, возможно, документация, поглядите что там пишут.

Comment: Неплохо бы указать версию студии (сейчас 2019 вышла, потихоньку переползать уже пора).

Comment: Этот nuget-пакет рассчитывает на установку через bower, а [в bs4 этот механизм не поддерживается](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24451). Используйте другие варианты, например через npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы устанавливаете bootstrap через nuget и этот способ в bootstrap 4 [является неподдерживаемым](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48481003/5752652). Действительно, всё пусто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, при установке в непустой шаблон студия может и явно выдать предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я рекомендую устанавливать пакет [при помощи npm](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/13.5.php):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом вам нужно не забывать, что файлы будут скачаны в папку node_modules и вам нужно будет переложить их в wwwroot, например - используя [штатный механизм bundle config](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/13.6.php):

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bootstrap.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bootstrap.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery.validate.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery.validate.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
    ]
  },
```

PS Если вы начинаете с шаблона пустого проекта - то вам нужно очень много шагов повторять вручную. Я бы рекомендовал поглядывать периодически на то, как устроены более типовые шаблоны и переносить подходящую логику к себе.

Comment: О, дивный мир фронтенда... Надо сказать, что я точно не понимаю, почему именно пакет не подходит - когда-то давно не стал погружаться в это, просто решил проблему установкой через npm (тем более что мне ещё тогда говорили, что bower потихоньку меняют на npm), но вот при написании ответа вижу, что не так всё очевидно. Уже не качнуть так просто 2017 студию, да и думаю нужна версия постарее - поэтому возможно мой ответ неточен в части причин почему не ставится, но рецепт предлагаю тот же: переходить на npm.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте установить Bootstrap с помощью Bower
http://prntscr.com/o9y7ca

Upd. При установке bootstrap c помощью NuGet можно обратить внимание на надпись "Несовместимо" и просьбу воспользоваться Bower (как у меня на скрине). Почему так можно почитать здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481003/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-in-asp-net-core

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]